# What are all the reasons for using a separate /31 subnet for a p2p link?

Tags: routing, ip, subnet

[image]

For example in this LAN, the 13.65 and 13.66 are a separate subnet between `slip` and `bsdi`, but what is the reason that they have a separate subnet?

The only reason i can think of is that `bsdi` cant have 2 interfaces on the same subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Routers route *between* subnets and each subnet needs to have a unique address/prefix. If a subnet is used for a point-to-point link only then /31 is the best choice you can make. Also common are /30 subnets but they waste 50% of their address space.

As a side note, purely point-to-point network interfaces like SLIP or PPP do not necessarily require an IP address of their own, depending on implementation.

Comment: Agreed, and to add emphasis that a /31 is primarily used to limit the waste of available IPs on a network when you have to have a transit network to allow routing between networks.

Comment: of course it would save IP addresses if there was no subnet at all, but that may require some kind of unusual setup, or not, depending on the hardware and software and protocols in use.

Comment: @user253751 When an interface type is purely p2p like with a serial interface then there's no addressing required.

Comment: And even on Ethernet, while addresses are required, those addresses don't nessacerally have to be unique, or be part of a subnet.